# Inno Setup give user choice of which application to associate extensions with

Tags: inno-setup

I have a setup project which installs three different executables.

I want to give users to option of associating multiple file extensions with either one of the exes or none of them. Is this possible, if so how?

The code I currently use to associate a single program with a file extension is:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; \    
    ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\program1.EXE,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; \
    ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\program1.exe"" ""%1"""
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What part of the task do you have problems with? An association of the extensions? Or a selection of the application to associate the extensions with?

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was quite specific :).

I have 3 programs 1.exe, 2.exe and 3.exe that are all installed with the inno installer

There are 2 extensions I want to associate with one or none of the progams .ext1 and .ext2

I want my users to be able to choose during the install process whether they associate 1.exe, 2, exe, 3.exe or nothing with the two extensions I listed

Comment: So the selection is the problem, correct? You already know how to associate the programs?

Comment: Yes - its how to make the selection optional - updated my original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["Tasks"](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection) to present a selection.

For example:

```
[Tasks]
Name: associate; Description: "Associate application with extension"
Name: associate\app1; Description: "Application 1"; Flags: exclusive
Name: associate\app2; Description: "Application 2"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: associate\app3; Description: "Application 3"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
```

[image: Tasks]

---

Then use the [`Task` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) in a respective section to select the correct operation for the registration.

In your case (association), it would be either

- [the `[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection), if you let the installer do the registration or
- [the `[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection), if you delegate the registration to some application.

---

Example for your `[Registry]` section entries:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: "{app}\program1.EXE,0"; Tasks: associate\app1
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: """{app}\program1.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: associate\app1

Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: "{app}\program2.EXE,0"; Tasks: associate\app2
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: """{app}\program2.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: associate\app2

Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: "{app}\program3.EXE,0"; Tasks: associate\app3
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: """{app}\program3.exe"" ""%1"""; Tasks: associate\app3
```

(I'm not sure about your `program1` key, shouldn't it be an extension or file type?)

---

To avoid repeating almost the same `Registry` entries, you can use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```pascal
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: "{app}\{code:AssociateExecutable},0"; Tasks: associate
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "program1\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; \
    ValueData: """{app}\{code:AssociateExecutable}"" ""%1"""; Tasks: associate

[Code]

function AssociateExecutable(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('associate\app1') then Result := 'program1.exe'
    else
  if IsTaskSelected('associate\app2') then Result := 'program2.exe'
    else
  if IsTaskSelected('associate\app3') then Result := 'program3.exe'
    else
  begin
    Log('No application selected, this should not happen');
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```